# Client/Server Sockets: How to make server push messages to client?

Tags: java, sockets, tcp

I am currently making a client/server application in Java that communicates through sockets. My experience with this type of programming is pretty limited, and I have only ever done request from client/response from server type of application. Now, I want to do it the other way around. That is, the client connects to the server and then just waits for the server to push messages at regular intervals to it.

The question is: How do I go about creating such an application? Or more to the point: How do I make the server write to the clients socket without first receiving a request and how can I keep the client listening for more messages?

Comment: How can you receiver an order without giving the shipping address?

Comment: The clients connect to the server first. That is the only thing they do, other than receiving data from the server later.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are mixing client and server logic and you should think about whether you server behaves more like a client. But ok...

First of all some java classes as entry point

[AbstractSelector](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/nio/channels/spi/AbstractSelector.html)

[SocketChannel](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/nio/channels/SocketChannel.html)

You can create a new Selector like

```
        // Create a new selector
        Selector socketSelector = SelectorProvider.provider().openSelector();

        // Create a new non-blocking server socket channel
        mServerChannel = ServerSocketChannel.open();
        mServerChannel.configureBlocking(false);

        // Bind the server socket to the specified address and port
        InetSocketAddress isa = new InetSocketAddress(mHostAddress, mPort);
        mServerChannel.socket().bind(isa);



        // Register the server socket channel, indicating an interest in
        // accepting new connections
        mServerChannel.register(socketSelector, SelectionKey.OP_ACCEPT);
```

The Selector can wait for inciming client connections

```
// Wait for an event one of the registered channels
mSelector.select();
```

and after a new client was connected, the AbstractSelector can be used to send responses to the client.

```
socketChannel.write(buf);
```

Example code:
http://rox-xmlrpc.sourceforge.net/niotut/

Comment: Thanks! Will check it out.

I know that what I want is kind of unusual for a server to behave. The server kind of has two modes, one where it continuously sends data to connected client(s) and one where it receives requests. I won't be using the request mode much (or at all).